# If JOIN and LEFT JOIN give the same response for a given table, which is faster?

Tags: mysql, join

Suppose a table `user` has `username` and `language_id`, and every user must have one and only one language_id. I can JOIN language_id to user to get more information about that user's language, and LEFT JOIN will give me the same information in my case. Which one will be faster? I'm not having performance issues, just trying to keep to best practices.

```
SELECT u.username, u.language_id, l.name AS language_name
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN language l ON u.language_id = l.id
```

Comment: join  (inner join)

Comment: If there is no reason to use outer join, don't do it.

Comment: An INNER join creates the *potential* for better query optimizations. It also more clearly shows the intent and expected cardinality.

Comment: Best practice would be to use the `JOIN` that's appropriate for the results you want and not rely on the fact that they both *happen* to provide the same results currently.

Comment: @lurker It's not that they both happen to give the same results. In my case, foreign keys and constraints require them to give the same results.